# Translate output to Japanese

Tags: python, internationalization, gettext, cjk, machine-translation

I'm planning to use Python Bottle framework for a simple website. Except for the numerics (eg., data shown in a table), all output has to be in Japanese. So instead of outputing "345.65 meters", I need to output "345.65 ".

Is there anyway I could create a text file containing (english) key = (japanese) value pairs ... something like:

```
meters = メートル  <-- love google translate 
seconds = ...
height = ....
Welcome = ... 
Error = ....
```

Then read this to a dictionary perhaps and translate my strings at run time: eg.,

```
settranslationfile("JapaneseWords.txt");
response.write( "<li"> + 345.65 + translate("meters") + "</li>" ).
```

I do not know Japanese or how Unicode/localization stuff works. If I have to, I'll try to learn how Unicode works ... but what's the path of least resistance to achieving this.  Any Python libs that do this?  A file like "JapaneseWords.txt" can most likely be filled in by the Japanese client and sent to me.

If there are such facilities in other frameworks, I would be willing to consider a switch over to them - preferably Python based frameworks and then Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you just described already exists and it is called [gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) (**edit**: also see Python's [`gettext`](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html#module-gettext) module). It does exactly that and I'm not sure if it the Bottle framework supports it but I do know that the [Django framework](https://www.djangoproject.com/) (also Python) does support it.

It should certainly be possible to integrate it into your Bottle web application but if you're willing to switch then here is the Django documentation on [internationalization and localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/).

Comment: Obviously python ships with it's own [gettext](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html#module-gettext) module.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus: Ah nice, how could I miss that :) In that case it's certainly possible to integrate it into Bottle, you'll just need to look into it how easily it can be integrated into a template language.

Comment: Thanks .. brief look at it seems like it will take some reading .. .mo files and whatnot.  Will take a more detailed look later  (hopefully this weekend) and see if it meets my needs. Will mark answer as correct if it does.

Comment: I have accepted this answer since I have not found any other module to do this. However, I feel the gettext solution might be overkill and overengineered for my purposes based on a cursory look at it. Would I lose something if I just write a small translation function that looks up a dictionary of translations. eg., T('hello') would look up 'hello' in a jpdict and return konichiwa in japanese if available; otherwise it returns back the english version as is.

Comment: Can anyone please document how to use `gettext` in templates? We are in lack of documentation